# Need jQuery's "when" functionality for mpromise/mongoose

Tags: javascript, deferred, deferred-execution

Is there such a thing as a when clause for mpromise/mongoose?  I'm looking to do something lke this without having to write my own wrapper for mpromise.

```
$.when(jQueryPromise1,jQueryPromise3,jQueryPromise3).done(function(r1,r2,r3) {
    // success code
}.fail(function(err1,err2,err3) {
    //failure code
});
```

I realize chaining exists, that's not what I want.  I'm looking for a mechanism in mpromise/mongoose that will execute when all promises have been completed.

Comment: Can you explain more why chaining is not what you want? I'm not familiar with this library; does chaining cause the promises to resolve sequentially instead of when ready?

Comment: Yes, chaining causes the promises to resolve sequentially, when I need them to resolve in parallel.  My application doesn't need the answers of one promise before executing the next, but I need do all results at once at the end of their execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample implementation of when:

```
function when(/* promise list */) {
    var promises = [].slice.call(arguments),
        whenPromise = new Promise,
        results = new Array(promises.length),
        remaining = promises.length,
        done = false,
        finish = function() {
            done = true;
        };

    whenPromise.onFulfill(finish).onReject(finish);

    promises.forEach(function(promise) {
        promise.onFulfill(function(result) {
            if (!done) {
                // index of result should correspond to original index of promise
                results[promises.indexOf(promise)] = result;
                if (--remaining == 0) {
                    // fulfill when all are fulfilled
                    whenPromise.fulfill.apply(whenPromise, results);
                }
            }
        }).onReject(function(err) {
            if (!done) {
                // reject when one is rejected (a la jQuery)
                whenPromise.reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a native solution, but I didn't find one.  I had to end up writing my own, but as yours works too, here's some points.

Comment: Thanks, I'd be curious to see your solution if you feel like sharing

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thinkingsites/9a4b4fe05a86c5dad210  It's leveraging packages I was already using, so it makes use of JQDeferred to implement when.  The primary difference in functionality is that I Can pass an array, or a list of arguments as the promise list, but that's nothing fancy, I just often have need to pass in dynamic arrays of promises.